# Oracle Database import .sql file by command prompt

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to import .sql file in Oracle by command prompt 
so please tell me that command to import .sql file in oracle 
in MYSQL I am using it like this

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost softpoint < D:\Nisarg\NEult\softpoint.sql
```

but In Oracle I don't know how to use this utility so please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Oracle, to run a script (*.sql) you use [SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref434)*PLUS command line utility.

```
c:\> sqlplus user_name/user_password@connect_string @path\your_sql.sql
```

Comment: you need to give full path ? like C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\demo\schema

Comment: what is @connect_string here?

Answer (score 8):

Try to use `sqlplus`:

```
  sqlplus user/password@connect @/Nisarg/NEult/softpoint.sql
```

[More information.](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/script.php)

Comment: How to import .dmp file with its .log to the already created database as the structure aresame

Answer (score 2):

It's worth knowing you can have a space between @ and the input file, which enables the use of the tab key auto completion.

Answer (score 0):

You can also export the SQLPATH environment variable (colon separated list of directories) for common scripts you don't want to bang out/tab complete the full path every time.