# Load database into terminal

Tags: database, terminal, sqlplus

For my SQLPLUS class, I am using terminal. I am needing to load this .sql database into my account [we enter in a school username and password to log in through it] so that I have all of the necessary tables for the class but I can't figure out how to load it into on my mac.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please enlighten us with the commands that you are using and what you have so far. Then point out what you are missing or where the problem occurs.

Comment: I am pretty clueless on anything as this is a beginner class and the professor was useless when I emailed. I have googled a bit but nothing is helping. The directions tell me to log on to oracle as administrator and run the db_load.sql script using @db_load which I don't understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle Database import .sql file by command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723152/oracle-database-import-sql-file-by-command-prompt)

Comment: Keep Googling ;) ask fellow students for help first before asking it here. This platform is not a place to dump your homework. Good luck!

Comment: This was not even homework. This is how to even access the homework problems. I did ask students but no one replied. This has been me searching for over a month, this is my last place to ask. I have only managed to get by so far by manually entering the information which is too time consuming.

Comment: Do you have Oracle installed? if so set your environment by typing .oraenv then the sid of your database (if not known type cat /etc/oratab and look on the list). Ne xt cd to the directory where the .sql file is. Login to sqlplus e.g. sqlplus / as sysdba or sqlplus user/pass. Check the database is started (e.g. select open_mode from v$database), if not started (logged in as sysdba) type startup. Next you can type @script.sql (where script.sql is the name of the file you wish to run).

Comment: Why are you manually entering in the data? Surely sou can just c+v from the file? It looks like from your response  you're just not @/path/to/script.sql or not in the directory where the script is when entering sqlplus.